# Get Data Sent by HttpPost in Java to php Script

Tags: java, php, android, http-post

My android app should send data to php script using HttpPost, the thing is I still can't receive any data to the php script, although I monitored that my app is sending data through the network. I used the following php code to get data:

```
<?php
$raw_post = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
echo $raw_post;
?>
```

Any suggestions to diagnose the problem and make sure if it is from my php side or the app side?

Comment: doc php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are uploading file using enctype="multipart/form-data", You'l have to get file reference in php:

```
<?php
$file=$_FILES['file_arg_name'];
$raw_post = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
echo $raw_post;
?>
```

Note: If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode(). see [PHP Doc for file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) for more details