# HTTP Post from Android to PHP backend

Tags: php, android

I want to do HTTP Post from Android to a backend server that will be running a PHP script to receive those data and save the contents to a text file.

For Android HTTP Post, I am following the example that can be found at http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

But, I couldn't find any reference for the backend PHP portion. The closest is PHP upload methods http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php but it is for file uploads.

There is an old post in SO [Get Data Sent by HttpPost in Java to php Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829228/get-data-sent-by-httppost-in-java-to-php-script) but no answers yet too.

Any idea how I could implement this? Basically I want to receive the posted data from Android and save the contents into a text file.

Comment: Are you sure that the request is sent? Could you paste some code to take a look at your approach?

Comment: is ur service on localhost or remote?

Comment: @Monica I am trying on a local host

Comment: @Cheluis I am using the code from http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: can u plz post url here? i wanana see that format

Comment: @Monica http://www.yoursite.com/script.php

Comment: @aandroidtest i think if u running in localhost then it should be : 127.0.0.1/script.com ? i waanna know ur actually url...is yuorsite.com is working in ur browser

Comment: @Monica The actual url is http://127.0.0.1/script.php

Comment: Use wireshark or some packet analyzer and check if the request is really sent to the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure your script.php is getting request or not.

**Testing On Emulator:** The localhost refers to the device on which the code is running, If its about the emulator then you'l have to use `IP address 10.0.2.2`.

**Testing On Device:** If you are testing your application on your physical device, then you'l have to turn on USB Tethering and then check the ip address associated between your device and pc. (Doesn't matter if Mobile Data is on or off)

In **Linux**, you can check that IP address using `sudo ipconfig`

It will o/p all network interfaces, from those you'l have to find the one with `usn0` or some similar.

```
usb0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:94:c7:0d:51:43  
      inet addr:192.168.42.106  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::494:c7ff:fe0d:5143/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2016 (1.9 KiB)  TX bytes:3978 (3.8 KiB)
```

Here you can see the device IP is **192.168.42.106** so, In Android you should use URL like,

```
http://192.168.42.106/script.php
```

In, **windows** it has similar command `ipconfig`.

**Android Source**

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.42.106/script.php"); // <-- for Device, and for emulator--> http://10.0.2.2/script.php 

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

After setting-up correct IP in Android code, read POST arguments in `script.php` and create a new file to store that data:

```
<?php
//getting data from POST request.
$arg1= $POST['id'];
$arg2= $POST['stringdata'];

//creating file
$ourFileName = "testFile.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't create file");

//wrinting content to file
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $arg1);
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $arg2);

//closing file
fclose($ourFileHandle);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `file_put_contents`?
https://www.php.net/file_put_contents

You can take your POST request string and write it to a file.

If the string is too large you might have to chunk it with something like `fwrite` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the [Doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

```
you should refer localhost as : 10.0.2.2

In your case u should change to  10.0.2.2/scipt.php
```